# iOS jailbreak exploits, The effects of exploits and how to manage them

Tags: ios, ios6, jailbreak, exploit, fuzzing

The [Syringe](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/syringe) project let's you "inject" [exploits](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/syringe/tree/master/syringe/exploits) to the iOS, but what does the  exploits actually do ?

When i look inside the [limera1n exploit](https://github.com/Chronic-Dev/syringe/blob/master/syringe/exploits/limera1n/limera1n.c), i don't get what it actually does, and i can't seem to find anyone explaining it either.

Basically what i want is to know more about how exploit codes work, and how you can find them (I read that Fuzzing is something very useful for this, but i couldn't find any way to do this for iOS, so please share some information on that as well).

I read the [iOS Hacker's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118204123) but that didn't go very "deep" into the exploit details, it only explained the basics of how it All works.

Overall i want to know more about the coding of exploits etc..

PS: Please don't hold back (if you know something, share it even if you can't "simplify it").